# FileContentResult from c# save as pdf from ajax call in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I am returning a pdf byte array from a c# controller as follows:

return new FileContentResult(pdfBytes, "application/pdf") { FileDownloadName = "test.pdf" };.

My client side code is as below. I am not able to successfully download the pdf from the response. I can see that it's returning the pdf in the response (by logging) but I am missing something here

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: config.ExportUrl,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        success: (response, status, error) => {

            this.isExporting = false;
            var defaultFileName = "test.pdf";


            var blob = new Blob([response]);
            var blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var anchor = document.createElement('a');
            anchor.download = defaultFileName;
            anchor.href = blobUrl;
            document.body.appendChild(anchor);
            anchor.click();
            document.body.removeChild(anchor);
            return response.content;
        },
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks
Angelo

Comment: Since you get the PDF file through an AJAX call, have you tried to use the `config.ExportUrl` as the url for the anchor instead?

Comment: I still need to POST the params, not sure how I can do that

Comment: I missed, that it is a POST request. What I wrote won't be possible then.

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar post like below and it worked:

```
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.responseType = "blob";
    req.open("POST", config.ExportUrl, true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200) {
            if (typeof window.chrome !== 'undefined') {
                // Chrome version
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(req.response);
                link.download = defaultFileName;
                link.click();
            } else if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
                // IE version
                var blob = new Blob([req.response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, defaultFileName);
            } else {
                // Firefox version
                var file = new File([req.response], defaultFileName, { type: 'application/force-download' });
                window.open(URL.createObjectURL(file));
            }
            //callback();
        }
    };
    req.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).